# Remove parts of a string ( ';' Semi-Colon Delimiter) and listing the remainder of the string in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to build a list within a single cell from a sting stored another cell. The string has a semi colon delimiter ';' to separate the string. I need to extract the CN=*, and remove the remainder, in the adjacent cell.

I've tried the following, but with little joy

=SUBSTITUTE(A87,";CN=",CHAR(10))

=SUBSTITUTE(A87,",",CHAR(10))

=SUBSTITUTE(A87,",",CHAR(10)&",CN=")

=SUBSTITUTE(A87,";",CHAR(10))

| String | Output |
| --- | --- |
| CN=User2,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User4,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User56,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User9,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Jane45 user,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User-Donna,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User76 smith,OU=blurb,OU=Test4,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Pink Panther,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Testing,DC=Testal;CN=Testuser78,OU=blurb,OU=Tester,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=great Scott,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Local;CN=Leah Human,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Alan Desai,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Duff Beer,OU=Groups,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,OU=Test76,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=simple user67,OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=test O'Lord,OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Concero,DC=Testal | CN=User2. CN=User4 CN=test O'Lord. CN=etc... |
| CN=User2,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User4,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User56,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=User9,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Jane45 user,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Pink Panther,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Testing,DC=Testal;CN=Testuser78,OU=blurb,OU=Tester,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=great Scott,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Local;CN=Leah Human,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Alan Desmond,OU=blurb,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal;CN=Duff Beer,OU=Groups,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Testal | CN=User2. CN=User4 CN=test O'Lord. CN=etc... |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL2jG.png)

Comment: What will you be using the output for? (Why have the output in 1 cell). Also, what version of Excel are you using? What have you tried yourself what is wrong with your own try?

Comment: Just for learning how to string manipulate in Excel. I'm using version Excel 2019 for Mac

Comment: I think VBA would be the easiest method.  You can use the `Split` function and extract all of what you want.

Comment: I connected using PowerShell and amended the string. 1. $strsplit = $LongString.Split(";") --- to split the string
2. $removesubstr = $strsplit -replace ",OU=*.*", "" --- to remove everything after the first comma and OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected using PowerShell and amended the string. I used the following website article to connect to the spreadsheet. https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/04/06/find-excel-data-with-powershell.aspx

The below is what I used, to append cell entries.

1. `$strsplit = $LongString.Split(";")` --- to split the string.
2. `$removesubstr = $strsplit -replace ",OU=*.*", ""` --- to remove everything after the first comma and OU.

Answer (score 0):

With ***Excel-365*** you may try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]"))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have Excel-365. So I cant use FILTERXML. I'm using Excel 2019 for Mac

Comment: Yes. MAC excel doesn't have `FILTERXML()` function.

Answer (score 0):

pls refer:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTERXML("<a><b><c>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</c></b><b><c>"),",","</c><c>")&"</c></b></a>","//c[1]"))
```

Comment: i don't have FILTERXML. Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm sending a new answer。

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If there were no `FILTERXL`, please refer:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SMALL(IF(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),3)="CN=",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),ROW($1:$30)),99),",",REPT(" ",30)),20)),""))
```